# setText can not be translated , how to string battery info to display correctly

Tags: android, string, settext, battery

hi i am trying to string the batteryinfo.setText, i have no idea how to do it. its working but information display is not accurate. help me to string correctly.

```
  public class Main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

            private TextView batteryInfo;



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                batteryInfo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.battinfo);

        his.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver,  new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));


         private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    int  level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
                    int  temperature= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
                    int  voltage= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);


               //issues fixed for setText can not be translated 



batteryInfo.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.battery_display),level,temperature,voltage));
                    }
                };

            }
```

### xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/battinfo"
        android:id="@+id/battinfo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
```

### string

//added battery display string

```
<string name="battinfo">Battery Status</string>
<string name="battery_display">BATT:  %1$d \n HEAT: %2$d °C\n  VOLT: %3$d \n</string>
```

Comment: @Robozorc what u want? which information is incorrect. Please describe

Comment: Display result BATT: 23  HEAT: 406 'C  VOLT: 3729   , what i want is    BATT: 23%  HEAT: 40.6 'C  VOLT: 3729mv @Jagjit Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the text you want to set in the `TextView` in `strings.xml`.

Your string will be:

```
<string name="battery_text" formatted="false">BATT:%d%% \n HEAT: %d &#8451; \n VOLT: %dmV</string>
```

In onReceive() take the string from strings.xml

```
batteryInfo.setText.(String.format(context.getString(R.string.battery_text),level,temperature,voltage));
```

Comment: code above giving this error:                                                              Error:(290) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?  ,  Error:(290) Unexpected end tag string    , Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common'.  and symbol R cannot be resolve

Comment: Updated ans please try now

Comment: awesome both issues fixed , thanks @zeus , how do i make HEAT: 46.5C instate of  showing HEAT: 460C

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
batteryInfo.setText ("BATT:  "+String.valueOf(level)+"%\n"+  "HEAT: "+String.valueOf(temperature)+"°C\n"+  "VOLT: "+String.valueOf(voltage)+"mV\n");
```

It will convert those variables from integer to string because textviews only accept strings.

ok Create Something like this on Strings.xml

```
<string name="battery_display">BATT:  %1$d \n HEAT: %2$d °C\n  VOLT: %3$d \n</string>
```

and on your activity

```
batteryInfo.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.battery_display),level,temperature,voltage));
```

Comment: still getting this warning :  Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders. the dispaly result are same as previous

Comment: edited the post, have added a new answer, please try it

Comment: issues solve for :setText can not be translated. Display result BATT: 23  HEAT: 406 'C  VOLT: 3729   is not accurate.

Comment: Great! did my answer helped you out?

Comment: thank you! your answer solve my ( setText can not be translated ) warning in my main.java. do you have any advice for this == Display result BATT: 23 HEAT: 406 'C VOLT: 3729 , But I wanted like this : BATT: 23% HEAT: 40.6 'C VOLT: 3729mv

Comment: okay Please mark the post as the solution :) Thanks
    you can change the strings.xml like this <string name="battery_display">BATT:  %1$d % \n HEAT: %2$d °C\n  VOLT: %3$d mv \n</string>